# Flutter Navigator not pushing onto the stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm experiencing a really strange problem with Flutter's navigation.

I'm using named routes. For this reason I'm supplying my `Navigator` with an `onGenerateRoute` method:

```
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    onGenerateRoute: Routes.onGenerateRoute,
    initialRoute: Routes.ROOT,
  );
```

here's my `onGenerateRoute`:

```
static Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case ROOT:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return MyRootPage();
          },
        );
      case PAGE_1:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return MyPage1();
          },
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        );
      case PAGE_2:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return MyPage2();
          }
        );
      default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, suppose I start my application landing on the `ROOT` route, and then I navigate to ´PAGE_1´ by using

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.PAGE_1)
```

Then I navigate to MyPage2 by using:

```
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.PAGE_2)`.
```

Here's the problem.

I'm expecting `MyPage2` to be pushed onto `MyPage1`, resulting in this widget tree:

```
MaterialApp
|__MyRootPage()
   |__MyPage1()
      |__MyPage2()
```

but instead, I get this:

```
MaterialApp
|__MyPage2()
|__MyRootPage()
   |__MyPage1()
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!